# How does a time varying magnetic field induce an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I've been trying really hard to understand this phenomena. Just exactly what happens in the region of space swarmed by this changing magnetic field that creates non electrostatic electric fields, microscopically? Why are they circular and always moving? Why can we not associate the concept of potential here? How are these moving $E$ fields facilitating flow of current if a conductor were to be placed there? 
Just this whole idea of non electrostatic electric fields(and hence currents) induced from changing magnetic fields is what I need clarity on.
I'm still a novice in physics and my understanding is broken, so feel free to correct me if my questions are incorrect.
Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This gets into areas where physics doesn't really tell us "why" something happens. We observe some phenomena, and physics just describes what we observe. You could even say that the whole concept of the electro-magnetic field is just a mental construct to help us describe observations, not necessarily "real".

Comment: This is a bit subtle but $\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$ doesn't actually state that a "time varying magnetic field induce(s) an electric field".  That is, it's not so much a causal relation as it is that one *implies* the other